# 2014 Dodge Grand Caravan will not shift out of park

Tags: dodge, shifting, caravan

I was wondering if anyone know where to start a repair on a 2014 Dodge Grand Caravan that will not shift out of park?

•   The “Malfunction Indicator Light” is currently on 
[image]
•   The “Electronic Stability Control (ESC) light” comes on at the same time as the “Malfunction Indicator Light”. 
[image]
•   When both lights are on, the van will not shift out of park.

Comment: Have you had the error codes read?

Comment: I assume it is still under warranty so it might be best to take it to the authorized service. Possible reason of not getting into gear is to save the car from further damage under the error indication. Problem can range from a simple fuse blowout to clutch/ transmission problems.

Comment: I highly doubt the van will not shift _because of_ the warning lights.  Whatever is causing the warnings is also causing it to not shift, and the only thing that I can think of is an electrical problem.  Without starting the engine, turn the key all the way on, put your foot on the brake and try to shift to neutral.  That _should_ work - otherwise how would you move a dead vehicle to tow it or push it around a workshop?

Comment: It sounds like the shift interlock is acting up I'd make sure that the brake lights work.

Comment: As suggested I took it to the dealer. The break switch failed. Thanks for the suggestions and insights.

Comment: Hey @Nick   Hoping you can answer your own question and mark it as answered.   Glad you got it fixed.  Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

As per [OP's comment](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26677/2014-dodge-grand-caravan-will-not-shift-out-of-park#comment42294_26677), the issue was a failed brake switch:

> As suggested I took it to the dealer. The break [sic] switch failed. Thanks for the suggestions and insights.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the cable that goes to the tranny is not jumped out of its slot.
If the gear stick has no resistance and slides like butter then it is pretty evident that the cable might be jumped off of its slot. I had this happen on an old car, but this is newer one they might not be using a cable at all.